# Very hard to interrupt python app (web server) from the windows CLI

Tags: windows, python-2.7, command-line-interface

Doing development on Windows 7. Running a python web server application via

```
server.serve_forever()
```

It is essentially impossible to interrupt it from the CLI with ctrl+z or ctrl+d (in PowerShell, cmd.exe or ConEmu). When I kill it via task manager it will dump a keyboard interrupt to the CLI, so it receives them, just doesnt stop.

Am I missing something? Is this simply the way I'm coding it? Dies gracefully via Task Manager, no big deal, but it is a PITA... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's just the way Win7 is. Linux isn't like this even on 1/4 the hardware. Closed.

Comment: Use Ctrl-c or ctrl-break on Windows. Windows isn't Linux.